# captive.apple.com/generate_204 hits from Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, url, browser, firewall

We have a several Windows 10 workstation - 6 out of 20  - constantly hitting the url "captive.apple.com/generate_204" over wired internet. Its not causing any issues but we don't understand why its happening and we want to turn it off.

Our FW logs give us this info which may be pertinent:

udp:6514
pan:threat
action  allowed

app web-browsing

app:default_ports   tcp/80

app:has_known_vulnerability yes

app:risk    4

app:subcategory internet-utility

app:technology  browser-based

app:tunnels_other_application   yes

app:used_by_malware yes

application web-browsing

category    computer-and-internet-info

content_type    text/html

dest    17.253.63.202

dest_hostname   captive.apple.com

dest_interface  ethernet1/4

dest_ip 17.253.63.202

dest_port   80

dest_zone   dsl

direction   client-to-server

filename    generate_204

flags   0x42b000

misc    captive.apple.com/generate_204

protocol    tcp

rule    User Internet Access - App

signature   URL Filtering log(9999)

signature_id    9999

src_interface   ethernet1/5.6

src_port    56363

src_translated_ip   192.168.50.1

src_translated_port 8089

threat_id   9999

threat_name -9999

type    THREAT

url captive.apple.com/generate_204

user_agent  Mozilla / 4.0

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem, but one of network administration. It is off-topic here. Perhaps Server Fault would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:google-chrome] and [tag:browser]? `user_agent Mozilla / 4.0` doesn't look like any common browser, let alone Google Chrome.

Comment: the url "captive.apple.com/generate_204" over wired internet — That isn't a URL, it lacks a scheme.

Comment: Thanks for replying  Quentin... I said its a url as the PAN logs says it is a url. Also the logs say the app is "web-browsing". The browser used by everyone Is Chrome

Comment: Assuming it came from a browser is probably a mistake.

Comment: Home come? The user shuts down his browser - we get none of this activity AND the logs says it' the browser. Maybe its the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. The GlobalProtect client for VPN access was hitting this "URL" to test for connectivity. I found out by eliminating what services were active on startup and it was the second one I tried.

Now we can eliminate this call-out as it is a trusted app that's doing it with no payload anyhow.

So it wasn't a browser but an embedded agent within the client